# Is there any openCV function to display its build option?

Tags: opencv, tbb, intel-ipp

I wonder there is any openCV function to display its library build option like if it is supporting TBB or IPP. Because I have a custom built openCV 3.0 library but the readme file doesn't mention whether TBB or IPP was implemented on it.

Thanks,

Comment: cerr << cv::getBuildInformation();

Comment: Thanks you, @berak!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a function, but the `cvconfig.h` header file contains the build information as defined (or not) macros.